# C++ Optimizar codigo demasiado lento

Tags: c++

Es un programa que te dice el valor de las vueltas en billetes y monedas. Pero es demasiado lento con valores mas complejos. Esta es una parte de la definicion de la funcion que hace el cambio, el resto es todo igual bajando el tamaño del billete o la moneda hasta llegar a 1 centimo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float cambio(float total, float importe)
{

    float x=0;
    int fivehun = 0, twohun = 0, onehun = 0, fifty = 0, twenty = 0, ten = 0, five = 0, two = 0, one = 0, ofifty = 0, otwenty = 0, oten = 0, ofive = 0, otwo = 0, oone = 0;

    if (total <= importe)
    {
        x = importe - total;


        if (x >= 500) //500
        {

            for (int i = 500; i <= x; i += 500)
            {
                fivehun++;
            }
        }
        x = x - fivehun * 500;


        if (x >= 200) //200
        {

            for (int i = 200; i <= x; i += 200)
            {
                twohun++;
            }
        }
        x = x - twohun * 200;
        
    }

    else 
    return 0;

    
}
```

Comment: como detalle: la funcion se encarga del proceso de "cambio" del dinero, no del "pago". por tanto, la logica de comprobacion de total <=importe no la tendrias que evaluar dentro de la funcion, sino fuera de esta, antes de llamarla.

Comment: No entiendo la necesidad de que sea mucho más óptimo. El código está bastante limpio; y aunque podría optimizarse para que las cantidades (500, 200, 100, etc) estuvieran en una estructura de datos, no hay mucho más que comentar. Respecto a lo que se comenta de cambiar float por int, no le va añadir mucha más rapidez y se va a dificultar la legibilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que haría es convertir la cantidad a entero. Esto te permite hacer operaciones de módulo con el número.

Dado que el tipo `int` no tiene decimales, tendremos que mover los decimales que nos interesan a la parte entera del número, en este caso nos interesan dos decimales:

```
int cantidad = static_cast<int>(x*100);
```

Después, basta con reemplazar los bucles por divisiones simples (recuerda multiplicar las cantidades por 100):

```
fivehun = cantidad / 50000;
cantidad %= 50000;

twohun = cantidad  / 20000;
cantidad %= 20000;

// ...
```

También sucede que las operaciones con enteros son más rápidas que las operaciones en coma flotante.